# How to paginate using version min max - VendHQ

Tags: php, loops, pagination

I'm wanting to paginate over the VendHQ API correctly. Is there an example I can look at to see how the version min / max works?

I'm sure this is a simple PHP loop, I've tried a few things but I don't know the best practice to do this. It would be great to see a code snippet on how to structure this correctly to query Vend.

https://docs.vendhq.com/reference/introduction/pagination#api-20

I expect the output will be the results from Vend which I can place into my own array to manipulate.

Comment: Do you want to iterate all data in a loop or create a html pager like `1 2 3 ... 123456`?

Comment: Hi @marv255 - Just want to loop over all the results and store in a array :)

If you look at the link I can do the API 0.x version - Just loop over the number of pages and get all results.

But never done the API 2.0 with min / max etc. not sure how to write the loop for that?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try. I think you already have http client if not you should get a look to [guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) or something similar.

There is a `max` parameter in every response, also you can set `after` parameter in your query to control current page. Do not tested, just an example so be careful:

```
//initializing guzzle
$guzzle = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://api.api/api']);
//current max number
$after = 0;
//array for all data
$allData = [];
//loop while collection in response doesn't empty
do {
    //querying current data piece
    $response = $guzzle->request(
        'GET', 
        '/api/2.0/products', 
        ['query' => ['after' => $after]]
    );
    //decoding response
    $responseBody = (string) $response->getBody();
    $decodedResponse = json_decode($responseBody, true);
    //here you can do some operations with $decodedResponse['data']
    //you can store all data to array but this is bad, you can catch 
    //Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted
    $allData = array_merge($allData, $decodedResponse['data']);
    //recording current max to $after
    $after = $decodedResponse['version']['max'];
} while (!empty($decodedResponse['data']));
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @marv255 definitly will give this a go!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but wanted to come back to this - @marv255 it worked perfectly, added my final code below to help someone else who might need the full answer.

---

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$sub_domain = 'vend-sub-domain';
$token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    // Base URI is used with relative requests
    'base_uri' => 'https://' . $sub_domain . '.vendhq.com/api/2.0/',
]);   


// Current max number
$after = 0;

//array for all data
$allData = [];

//loop while collection in response doesn't empty
do {
    //querying current data piece
    $response = $client->request(
        'GET',
        'products',
        [
          'headers'  => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token
          ],
          'query' => ['after' => $after]
        ]
    );

    //decoding response
    $responseBody = (string) $response->getBody();
    $decodedResponse = json_decode($responseBody, true);
    //here you can do some operations with $decodedResponse['data']
    //you can store all data to array but this is bad, you can catch
    //Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted
    $allData = array_merge($allData, $decodedResponse['data']);
    //recording current max to $after
    $after = $decodedResponse['version']['max'];

} while (!empty($decodedResponse['data']));


echo '<pre>';
print_r($allData);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Can we filter vendHq consignments by updated date ?